# Bootstrap AJAX tabs don't work, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on "Tools" tab, **nothing** happens: tabs don't switches, not toggles.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(e) {
 var $this = $(this),
  loadurl = $this.attr('href');

 $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
  $('#content').html(data);
 });

 $this.tab('show');
 return false;
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
        <li role="navigation" class="active"><a href="/engine/ajax/main.php" aria-controls="main" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">My links</a></li>
        <li role="navigation"><a href="#tools" aria-controls="stat" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Statistics</a></li>
        <li role="navigation"><a href="/engine/ajax/tools.php" aria-controls="tools" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tools</a></li>
        <li role="navigation"><a href="#payments" aria-controls="payments" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Payments</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="container">

    </div>
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: I do it by this tutorial: http://jsfiddle.net/adrienne/La2765jn/

Answer (score 0):

Put

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

before

`<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

like this:

`<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

bootstrap.min.js requires jquery.min.js to run first before it.